# Why should I pluralize controller name for RESOURCE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, naming-conventions, routes, conventions

I understand that there is a convention, about controllers' names so it should be pluralised.

But why should I pluralize controller's name for resource?

So this is ok:

```
resources :apples
```

But this is not:

```
resource :apple, :controller => "apple"
```

Why just not?

```
resource :apple
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resource` is different from `resources`.  It's used if you have just one.

As [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) explains, it's useful if you only ever reference one.  If you have, for example, a profile that you never mention the id, you just assume the current user needs to access or edit their own profile.

You can mix these, too.  So say you want users to be able to view each other's profiles, but also have a url for their own profile:

```
resources :profiles
resource :profile
```

Comment: ok I know that :) I am talking about naming convetion. Why should I pluralize my resource?

Comment: Well, do you have more than one?  Maybe this should go on http://english.stackexchange.com/ (I kid, I kid.)

Comment: No, I have got just one apple - but my controller is still pluralized :)

Comment: The assumption is that there are multiple apples, but you don't reference them by id.  This is likely because of the usecase I mentioned.

Comment: I came looking for confirmation of my annoyance, but found interesting new information instead :) Thanks.